# JTabbedPane component accessing

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I use `JTabbedPane` in one of my Java GUI code. I use the following portion of code to instantiate and maintain the `tabpane`.

```
JTabbedPane tabpane =  new JTabbedPane();  
PageViewer pv = new PageViewer();  
tabpane.addTab("tabttitle", new JScrollPane(pv));
```

`PageViewer` is an extended class of `JEditorPane`. I want to access and modify the currently selected tab's constituent `PageViewer pv` component. I tried the following lines of code with some values of `ind`.

```
JScrollPane jsp = (JScrollPane) tabpane.getComponentAt(tabpane.getSelectedIndex());  
PageViewer pv2 = (PageViewer) jsp.getComponent(ind);
```

But for `ind==0` compiler says `"java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JViewport cannot be cast to menu_window.PageViewer"`.

For `ind==1` it says `"java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar cannot be cast to menu_window.PageViewer"`.

For `ind==2` output is `"java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar cannot be cast to menu_window.PageViewer"`.

And for `ind>=3` error is `"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 3"`.

Now how do I do the desired job, if anyone knows please help.

Note: I use NetBeans 6.8 with Java 6 Standard Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a JScrollPane around a component, the scrollpane actually adds the component into an internal JViewPort.  To get the original component from the scrollpane you can do this:

```
PageViewer pv2 = (PageViewer)jsp.getViewport().getView();
```